# Jetpack Compose Remove `material-icons-extended` unused icon

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

As mentioned on this page, unreferenced icons can be deleted through R8/Proguard, how do I delete them?

https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/icons/package-summary

Comment: You don't have to manually delete them. Whenever you build a variant of your app with minification enabled, all the unused resources will be stripped away from the final app

Comment: That's your answer, consider posting and accepting it yourself if the original poster does not do the same.